# Hudson deployed in websphere asking username and password to login

Tags: websphere, hudson

I deployed Hudson war in Websphere 8.5 and it was successfully deployed and first time I tried the Hudson url workied fine and in the Manage Hudson I confifured LDAP details and saved without validated. Now when I tried the Hudson url http://localhost:port/hudson it is always asking the User name and password tried a lot uninstall the Hudson application deleted the profile recreated and redeployed Hudson but still Hudson is asking the User name and password. I am unable to find the config directory in websphere and also I don't know how to by pass this. Please any body help on this where to change and to go Manage Hudson page without login.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at root configuration file config.xml stored in HUDSON_HOME directory. This config file contains configured user security and LDAP configuration.
Find line

```
<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
```

and replace it with

```
    <useSecurity>false</useSecurity>
```

HTH